# UPS shipping options not showing

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, ups

I have setup live site in my local server, all functionalities are working good except UPS shipping method.

I have update UPS settings as it is at live site like this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6875

I have check debog.log  file and showing this error:

```
    <Package>
      <PackagingType><Code>00</Code></PackagingType>
      <PackageWeight>
         <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>1</Weight>
      </PackageWeight>
    </Package><RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation>  </Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>',
  'result' => 
  array (
    'error' => 'Could not resolve host: onlinetools.ups.com',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

Can anyone help me, What i need to do to make working UPS shipping method?

Any help will be appreciated.